# Is there any offline alternative to cloud9?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, git, express, cloud9-ide

I am learning web development using online course. And when the backend development started, i was asked to create an account on cloud9 but cloud9 stopped signups.
So is there any offline alternative to cloud9?
I am using windows 10.
In further lessons, the use of terminal, nodejs, npm, express, mongodb, git is there.

Comment: Alternative in what regard? There are many IDEs (both online and offline) that allow you to do web development and many text editors are good enough to get the job done as well. Is there some specific functionality in Cloud9 that you are trying to find elsewhere?

Comment: Also Cloud9 got absorbed into AWS a few years ago. If your development course is telling you to create a Cloud9 account, I would take it as a red flag that the course material might be dated and that maybe you should look for a more recent course elsewhere.

Comment: In the course, the instructor uses terminal and installs express,mongodb using the terminal. He creates .js files and after writing code, using terminal he runs that file (example, he created a file called app.js and after writing code in it, he wrote this command in terminal- node app.js and pressed enter and the server started. after that he clicked on the run button and a webpage opened, and the url was localhost:8000). So since i cannot create an account on cloud9 so is there any offline alternative? Since i completed 50% of the course, it is difficult to start another course.

Comment: If your only requirement is to be able to use a terminal, then there are literally hundreds of options to choose from. The option pool opens wider still when you consider that there's not really any reason to _require_ that the IDE has an integrated terminal - it's quite simple to have the editor and a standalone terminal open and switch between them.

Comment: If you are absolutely married to the idea of using a direct Cloud9 alternative, then you should create an AWS account and use Cloud9 there. (AWS has a free tier, but I'm not certain if it covers Cloud9 and it's accompanying EC2 instance.) Otherwise, pick any popular IDE or lightweight code editor with node.js support and try your best to translate the instructions.

Comment: So what will you suggest? I checked the further videos of the course, the use of terminal, .js files, starting server, .ejs files is maximum. I am using windows 10. The instructor used macos.....

Comment: [Asking for a specific recommendation is beyond the scope of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Even ignoring that, I can't give you a specific recommendation because (as I said) there are literally hundreds of options, any of which is a 5 second Google search away. My suggestion is to either use AWS Cloud9 or do some of your own research to see which IDE or code editor you like. (If you're planning on being a web developer, this is good practice for you anyway.)

Comment: look, regarding terminal, nodejs and express i can use an ide but what about the server thing that is constantly used in the course. Cloud9 has it's own server but what to do about it when not using cloud9?

Comment: The server is an instance of node/express being hosted on the local machine and has absolutely nothing to do with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative to Cloud9 as in an editor where you can code offline on your desktop and then sync your code to a cloud server version of the same editor (synchronously or asynchronously), then check out https://www.eclipse.org/che/

If you just need a code editor, there are several options available -

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

https://atom.io/

https://code.visualstudio.com/

As an additional note, if you are looking for an online code editor or IDE, check out these -

https://codeanywhere.com/

https://www.koding.com/